# A Fossil of a Puzzle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

Here's a poetic identification riddle for everybody. Good Luck!

> *Type* of a *card*, not for *gifts* or to *play*
>
> Or a *root* of a *plant* of a *tea*, in a *way*
>
> I have *wings*, I can *fly*, I'm a *crea*ture of *past*
>
> It is *fi*nally *time*, a re*quest* I must *ask*,
>
> ***What am I?***

**Hint 1:**

> My suffix is hidden in how the above is read, 
>  I am stressing you pay attention to how it is said

**Hint 2**

> To find my end, the tags may help thee, 
>  it is a device just over 3 feet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type of a card, not for gifts or to play

> **TAROT**

Or a root of a plant of a tea, in a way

> **TARO**

I have wings, I can fly, I'm a creature of past

> **PTERO**dactyl

The hints and the poetry tag suggest that the answer is

> **Pterodactylic tetrameter**  
>  (The meter of the poem is *dactylic tetrameter*.)

Comment: You pretty much have it there is a final clue to narrow it down hidden in how it is written.

Comment: I would say the answer is Tarot as “on a ROOT of a plant of a Tea”, which means the word ends in T

Comment: It says 'or' not 'on' and they were right Taro is a root based plant that is used in/for teas

Comment: I'm going to give it to you since you pretty much have it. The third homophone was the goal and the poetic meter was there to clue as to which homophone.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Divination?

*A Fossil of a Puzzle*

> Perhaps referring to how fortune-telling is no longer widely accepted in the modern day?

*Type of a card, not for gifts or to play*

> Tarot cards are neither intended to accompany gifts and are not playing cards, their intention is to divide the future.

*Or a root of a plant of a tea, in a way*

> The way that plants grow or tea leaves settle in the bottom of a mug are often used to interpret a person's fortune.

*I have wings, I can fly, I'm a creature of the past*

> Often in stories, dragon bones are cast to make predictions. Dragons are mythical being predominantly from the bygone medieval era.

*It is finally time, a request I must ask*

> A reference to how people request fortunes that transcend time, such as asking for the date when they die or such.

Comment: Sadly it isn't what I was looking for, but I am very impressed with how well it fits.